# open android app from browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, xamarin.android, android-deep-link

I am trying to open my android application after my web page is loaded, using javascript. I see lot of answers on stackoverflow for this, but not one of them seem to work for me.

In chrome | default mobile browser my link seems like:

```
<a href="myappschema://myapphost/" id="deeplink" > return back to my app </a>
```

This work fine when user clicks on the link but how I can call it from javascript after page loaded?

I tried using jquery and javascript, as shown below, with no success. Any help?

1-

```
 window.location.href = "myappschema://myapphost/";
```

2-

```
 setTimeout(function () {
                  jQuery('#deeplink')[0].click();
                    }, 3000);
```

In My Activity I added:

```
  [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", MainLauncher = true,
            WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustResize,
            Icon = "@mipmap/ic_logo_2", Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash")]
        [IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView,Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable,Android.Content.Intent.ActionDefault },
        DataScheme = "myappschema",
        DataHost = "myapphost",
        DataPathPrefix = "/",
        Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable,Android.Content.Intent.ActionDefault })]
   public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, NavigationView.IOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
    {}
```

Comment: Did you define the URI schema in your app?

Comment: yes I add the URI schema to my activity

Comment: Could you add that to your question?

Comment: one thing I noted that it's work fine in older version of chrome